# How to disable automatically adding semicolons to end of lines in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Note: Everyone trying to say this is not default behavior for Visual Studio and must be an addon/extension/setting... please validate that assumption before stating it as fact. I've done the testing. It's default behavior. Install Visual Studio on a new machine with factory default settings and this behavior is present. No extensions, addons, or anything. It was added in version 16.1, as it does not happen prior to that version of Visual Studio. I cannot identify the actual name of this feature or how to disable it.

---

I'm trying to figure out how to disable the feature described in this [Developer Community post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/588114/vs-1611-typed-semicolon-jumps-to-next-line.html).

This is not behavior added by an addon or extension. It is present in a fresh install of VS 2019.

Comment: By default, Visual studio does not add semi-colon at the end of every line. Removing any 'plugins' you installed would remove the features that they would come with.

Comment: @Jawad I suggest you review the link I provided. This is default behavior. Removing plugins and extensions was the first thing I did.

Comment: I just confirmed this behavior is present in a newly installed copy of Visual Studio 2019 with no addons or extensions.

Comment: The link you provided states that this is not default behavior, but rather that you need to install the Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: @ckuri read more than the first post. Further down, a user says this is default behavior added by a subsequent update. Also see my comment where I said it happens on a fresh install. Also see my edit where I link an MS post saying this is a behavior of VS's Complete Statement feature but does not say how to disable it.

Comment: I have the lastest production version of VS (16.6.3) and it does not do this automatically. My guess is that some config is doing that. And, of course, the personal config are carried to fresh installs because of the e-mail that you use to login. So, I suggest you to reset the VS configuration to factory defaults, or try a fresh install in another computer with another email.

Comment: @Guilherme I completely uinstalled and reinstalled VS from scratch. I confirmed it is in fact present with factory default settings in the latest versions of VS. I also confirmed it is not present below version 16.1

It is default behavior present in a default install of Visual Studio with factory settings. I would very much like to know what you did to apparently disable this feature.

Comment: Developer community link you posted is about something "totally different". Visual studio 2019 is smart enough to know at some places where the semi colon should go. If you type semi colon in the middle of a block, where it shouldnt, semi colon will automatically go to the end of the block, where it "should".

Comment: @JustinMoore `I would very much like to know what you did to apparently disable this feature.` Well, guess what, I want to know how you enabled =D.... But seriously, this is not the default behavior for sure. Reasons: 1) A "fresh" install of VS does not delete your configuration files. 2) None of the people here had this problem. 3) As @Jawad correctly pointed out, the links you provided talks about other issues. Anyway, I would suggest you to try this in a friend's computer. You will see that this is in fact not the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Only place I was able to find where you can change the semicolon preference was under Tools > options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Formatting > General

Last section of the General has Semicolon Preference where you can "Insert Semicolons at statement ends. If you have a check there, remove it.

The links you have posted in your question talks about, 'semicolon automatically **moving** to the end of the statement', rather than Visual Studio **adding** a semi-colon at the end of the statement.

This is explained in your other [Developer post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/589478/view.html):
*The semicolon is being moved by the Complete Statement feature. Since the semicolon was typed inside an argument list where a semicolon is not valid, the feature assumes you want to complete the collection initializer statement by putting a semicolon at the end*

I dont believe there is any way of turning that off. I can recommend using Visual Studio Code that allows behavior like adding semicolons without automatically moving it to the end.

Answer (score 0):

There now is a setting under Text Editor->C#->Intellisense "Automatically complete statement on semicolon" that is responsible for this mad man behavior.

Why this was implemented for C# where a misplaced semicolon almost never can cause runtime errors since the compiler will catch it I fail to understand despite reading through all the comments on GitHUb with users complaining of the feature and microsoft defending it.

If anyone actually have had this help them ever, please explain in what case :D